# Socket.io-1.0 get clients from namespace

Tags: socket.io-1.0

I work with socket.io 1.0 and maybe I'm wrong with my conception.

Actually, I open a namespace server side with

```
var nsp = io.of('/myNamespace');
```

And clients connect with

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost/myNamespace');
```

I can start communication without problems.
Server side I catch signals with

```
nsp.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        //problem here
    });
});
```

In the disconnect I would like to disconnect all sockets connected to my namespace, so i tried to do

```
for(var myParticipantID in io.sockets.adapter.nsp.connected)
{
    io.sockets.adapter.nsp.connected[myParticipantID].disconnect();
}
```

but it doesn't work ... I don't have error but clients still connecting
I tried with

```
io.sockets.nsp.clients();
```

but I have error since socket.io 1.0

I don't want to create room, but maybe it's my mistake?

Thanks for your help,
MagicDenver

Answer (score 0):

If it would help somebody, 
I work with node js so I created a value:

```
app.set(idNameSpace,[]);
```

and push socket when I have a new connection

Answer (score 0):

You should use the **io.of(namespace)** function to get connected clients.

```
for (var id in io.of('/namespace').connected) {
    var s = io.of('/namespace').connected[id];

    s.disconnect();
}
```

If you don't know the namespace and you are in a socket.on statement, you can use `socket.nsp.connected` instead of `io.of('/namespace').connected`